# formhandler typo3 feuser double opt in

Tags: typo3

I have a user registration form with the extension formhandler and a user is created in the right sysfolder. But the double opt in link which is created and send via e-mail does not work. The user is still hidden. I think that the link does not include the sysfolder with the feuserdata. When I click the link I get the error message: that the authorization code is not found and maybe the authorization has already been done. But that is not true.

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.register {
name = Formhandler User Registration
templateFile = typo3conf/templates/main/plugins/formhandler/register.html
disableWrapInBaseClass = 1
formID = registration
formValuesPrefix = feregistration
isErrorMarker.default = error
isErrorMarker {
    global = error
}

preProcessors {
    1.class = PreProcessor_LoadGetPost
    2.class = PreProcessor_ValidateAuthCode
    2.config {
        redirectPage = 1045
        hiddenField = hidden
        selectFields = email
        additionalParams = COA
        additionalParams {
            10 = TEXT
            10.value = &pid=1044
        }
    }
}
finishers {
    1.class = Finisher_DB
    1.config {
        table = fe_users
        fields {
            pid.postProcessing =  1044
            email.mapping = email
            username.mapping = email
            password.mapping = password
            password.special = saltedpassword
            password.special.field = password
            first_name.mapping = firstname
            last_name.mapping = name
            address.mapping = streetno
            usergroup.ifIsEmpty = 1
            disable.ifIsEmpty = 1
        }
    }
    2.class = Finisher_GenerateAuthCode
    2.config {
        table = fe_users
        fields {
            pid.postProcessing = 1044
        }
        selectFields = email
    }
    3.class = Finisher_DB
    3.config {
        table = fe_users
        updateInsteadOfInsert = 1
        fields {
            fe_cruser_id.special = inserted_uid
            fe_cruser_id.special.table = fe_users
        }
    }
    4.class = Finisher_Mail
    4.config {
        checkBinaryCrLf = message
        admin {

            to_email = admin@mail.de

            subject = TEXT
            subject.dataWrap = Neue Registrierung: {GP:formhandler|firstname} {GP:formhandler|name}
            sender_email = email
            replyto_email = email
        }
        user {
            to_email = email
            to_name = name
            subject = Vielen Dank für deine Registrierung
            sender_email = user@mail.de
            sender_name = user
            replyto_email = user@mail.de
            replyto_name = user
        }
    }
    5.class = Finisher_SubmittedOK
    5.config {
        returns = 1
    }
}
```

}

I tried to include the sysfolder pid as an additional parameter but the url does not get this parameter.

Comment: are you using the extension formhandler_subscription?

Comment: No I just use the extension formhandler. I do not know if the subscription extension works with typo3 6.1.

Comment: I dont'know about your ts above (is that really all it takes to create the authentication mail??) but have a look at the extension - it's mainly ts for formhandler and some helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your preProcessor, `hiddenField` should be `disable`. This is the name of the field you want to set to 0 if the auth code is validated. You should also ensure there actually is an hidden field in your form named `disable` and with value 1.